# Why Observable.zip doesn't call finallyDo?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

Simply, I have this code. But finallyDo is never called for Observable.zip ...Why?

```
Observable<Integer> observable1 = Observable.just(1);
Observable<Integer> observable2 = Observable.just(2);
Observable<Double> observable = Observable.zip(
    observable1,
    observable2, 
    (Func2)(t1,t2)->{return (double)t1/(double)t2;}
);
observable.finallyDo(()-> {Log.e("","Done");});//is never called;
observable.subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: Try doOnTerminate instead unless you really want your action to execute after the terminal event (complete or error) instead of just before.

Answer (score 4):

`Observable` doesn't use the Builder pattern, thus you should subscribe to the instance returned from `finallyDo()`:

```
observable.finallyDo(()-> {Log.e("","Done");}).subscribe()
```

Comment: @Nick in the precisely same usage? Shouldn't be possible, since your previous operator returns a new observable that you ignore.